# Error: Maven2RepositoryLayoutFactory: Unsupported repository layout legacy

Tags: spring, maven, log4j

I get this error message from maven:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project battleships: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.miteff.travelex:battleships:wa
r:2.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1, com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1, com.s
un.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1: Could not transfer artifact javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1 from/to java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/no
nav/repository): Cannot access https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository with type legacy using the available connector
 factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository with type legacy u
sing the available layout factories: Maven2RepositoryLayoutFactory: Unsupported repository layout legacy -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I have almost blank Spring project with log4j. Log4j is registered this way

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Show your repository configuration in pom.xml

Comment: There are no additional repositories added to pom.xml

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two solutions known to me:

1. Update log4j version to 1.2.17 solves the issue.
2. Stay with log4j version 1.2.15, but add scope runtime to it in this way:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.15</version>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```

Comment: thanks @joro you just saved me some time! ;)

Comment: There is one other way See https://crunchify.com/maven-artifacts-error-jms-jmxtools-jmxri-dependencies/

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to solve this problem is to have simple maven 2 side project into which I put the failed dependencies. I then run maven 2 against this project, the dependencies download fine and then maven 3 finds them.

I tried using update policy 'always' but that didnt always work.